# I could not understand the value into the xlim and ylim. What is that?

Tags: r

```
library(maps)
library(mapdata)
map("worldHires","Canada”, xlim=c(-141,-53), ylim=c(40,85), col="gray90”, fill=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Those stand for 'x axis limits' and 'y axis limits'.  The first number is the minimum value for the axis (all the way at the left side for x, or bottom for y).  The second number is the corresponding maximum value for the axis.  You can set those to display whatever region of the space you prefer.

Comment: Thank you so much @gung. But how can I get the minimum and maximum value of X and Y for a specific location? Suppose What will be the value of Min and Max value of Dhaka City, Bangladesh.

Comment: *You* set the min & max for whatever you want them to be, @Xabir. I would suggest an X min to the left of Dhaka, & a X max to the right of the city, & likewise a Y min below town, w/ Y max above.

Comment: If i want to draw a simple map of location of which the latitude is 23.777176 and the longitude is 90.399452, then how will I draw it with R?

Comment: I don't actually know, @Xabir, but `xlim` & `ylim` are generic plotting arguments in R. I would suggest you set x min <90.399452, x max >90.399452, y min <23.777176, & y max >23.777176.

Comment: You're welcome, @Xabir. If this resolved your issue, you might consider accepting it by clicking the check mark below the vote total to its left (or don't, if your concern is not yet resolved).